# curand_init() produces memory access errors

Tags: cuda

In my program I have to generate a lot of random numbers. Therefore, I try to reuse cuRAND-states so that I do have to initialize them only once. Unfortunately, the code that does the initialization produces weird memory access errors. I spent a lot of time debugging it and the errors occure only when I set the parameter 'sequence' of 'curand_init()' to a big value (30000 for example) or when the parameter 'seed' get's too big. 
With the following code I'm able to reproduce the error:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

__global__ void initRnd(unsigned long long seed, curandState* states, int size)
{
    int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (id < size) {
        curand_init(seed, id, 0, &states[id]);
    }
}

void handleError(cudaError_t code)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("ERROR: %s (Code: %d) %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), code, __FILE__, __LINE__);
        exit(code);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int size = 3000000;

    cudaError_t code = cudaSetDevice(0);
    handleError(code);

    curandState *data;
    code = cudaMalloc((void**)&data, size * sizeof(curandState));
    handleError(code);

    const int blockSize = 256;
    int numOfBlocks = (size + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    dim3 dimGrid(numOfBlocks);
    dim3 dimBlock(blockSize);
    initRnd << <dimGrid, dimBlock >> > (time(0), data, size);
    code = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    handleError(code);

    code = cudaDeviceReset();
    handleError(code);

    printf("\nPress any key...\n");
    _getch();
}
```

When I run this with cuda-memcheck it delivers unpredictible results and sometimes my computer crashes.

The errors disappear When I set the sequence-parameter of curand_init to 0:

```
curand_init(seed, 0, 0, &states[id]);
```

Since that results in having the same sequence in all threads I tried to add the thread-id to the seed-value:

```
curand_init(seed+id, 0, 0, &states[id]);
```

But then the Errors reappear when 'id' contains high values.

I'm quite new to cuda-programming and I'm not shure if I do something wrong or if that's a bug in cuRAND that I should file to NVidia.

Can anyone help?

## Update:

To check whether this is a bug in my program or somewhere in Cuda I used the first example from chapter 3.6. ("Device API Examples", see [cuRAND Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#thrust-and-curand-example)). It also produces memory access violations in cuda-memcheck. So I guess that it's either a bug in cuRAND or in the memory checker. Could someone please verify this? Is someone able to run the example whith cuda-memcheck without errors?

btw: The problem exists even with other cuRAND-generators like curandStatePhilox4_32_10_t or curandStateMRG32k3a.

## Update 2

It's not cuda-memcheck that reports false errors. It's Nsights with the memcheck-option turned on. It seems to be independent from cuRAND. Nsight reports memory access errors even in some of the simple cuda-examples. Sorry for the misleading information in the text above.

Comment: It appears that you are on windows.  This may be just a WDDM TDR for large sizes of the kernel grid.

Comment: That's right. I'm on windows. But TDR is switched off on my machine.

Comment: I ran your code on linux/CUDA8/K20x.  It runs fine, with or without `cuda-memcheck`.  However, with `cuda-memcheck` it takes a *very* long time to run.

Answer (score 4):

After I've done a lot more debugging it turned out that curand works just fine. It's the nsight-debugger that produces false error messages.

Especially, with the option **Enable Cuda Memory Checker** turned on. Quite often it reports errors where cuda-memcheck finds nothing at all.

Also, it often reports **false** failed assertions. Up to now I couldn't figure out what causes the problem. Probably there's a bug in my code that causes this weird behavior.

Or there is something wrong with the configuration of my machine. In the meantime I installed a couple of updates of CUDA that came with new drivers. So it seems unlikely that CUDA itself causes the problem.

However, I just wanted to let you know that CURAND did not cause the trouble.